# How to connect to PostgreSQL from Phoenix Web App via SSL?

Tags: postgresql, azure, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

When trying to run Elixir (Phoenix) Web Application using PostgreSQL Database hosted 3<sup>rd</sup> party "**Database-as-a-Service**" ([*Azure Database for PostgreSQL*](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/postgresql)).

We attempt to start the app with `mix phoenix.server` we see the following error:

```
[info] Running Pxblog.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://localhost:4000
[error] GenServer #PID<0.247.0> terminating
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Postgrex.Messages.decode_fields/1
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/messages.ex:339: Postgrex.Messages.decode_fields("")
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/messages.ex:344: Postgrex.Messages.decode_fields/1
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/messages.ex:344: Postgrex.Messages.decode_fields/1
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/messages.ex:131: Postgrex.Messages.parse/3
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:1842: Postgrex.Protocol.msg_decode/1
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:1816: Postgrex.Protocol.msg_recv/3
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:560: Postgrex.Protocol.auth_recv/3
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:475: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:134: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
```

### Insight: "Enforce SSL" was Enabled on the Azure DB ...

Through investigation we realised that the error is cause because the Azure PostgreSQL Service had `Enforce SSL Connection` set to `Enabled` (*by `default`*):

[image: azure-psql-ssl-enabled]

We think having "Enforce SSL" to `Enabled` is **good** for **Security**, but we aren't able to get it working with Phoenix ...

### (*Temporary*) Solution: *Disable* "Enforce SSL"

So, we have (*temporarily*) *disabled* SSL for now:
[image: azure-psql-ssl-disable]

But we would *much prefer* a "*permanent*" solution to this issue.

### *Preferred* Solution: Use SSL when Connecting to PostgreSQL

If anyone can clarify (*or point us to*) ***how*** to connect to PostgreSQL over SSL from Phoenix/Ecto 
we would be super grateful! :-)

Does the Application (Phoenix) Server need to have an SSL Certificated configured in order to connect from the App server to the DB Server...? 
e.g: http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/configuration-for-ssl ?

Microsoft has the following help guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-ssl-connection-security
It *seems* to suggest we need OpenSSL on the App Server ... can anyone *confirm*?

Comment: Have you tried setting `ssl: true` in the repo configuration?

Comment: @michalmuskala sadly, simply adding `ssl: true` in `Repo` section of `prod.secrets.exs` does not solve the issue. we tried it: https://git.io/v9Ne2 :-( we _suspect_ SSL Certificates may be required for this to work.

Comment: @nelsonic What error do you get with `ssl: true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Background

I was experiencing the same problem connecting Phoenix/Ecto/Postgrex to Azure Database for PostgreSQL server. Even after setting `ssl: true` in my Repo configuration, I was still not able to connect to the database with Postgrex even though connecting using `psql "postgresql://...?sslmode=require" -U ...` on the same machine succeeded. The error returned with `ssl: true` was:

```
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.1853.0>) failed to connect: **(DBConnection.ConnectionError) ssl connect: closed

** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) connection not available because of disconnection
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:926: DBConnection.checkout/2
    ...
```

After digging through the source code, I discovered that the failing call was actually the `ssl.connect/3` call from [the Erlang ssl module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html):

```
# deps/postgrex/lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:535

defp ssl_connect(%{sock: {:gen_tcp, sock}, timeout: timeout} = s, status) do
  case :ssl.connect(sock, status.opts[:ssl_opts] || [], timeout) do
    {:ok, ssl_sock} ->
      startup(%{s | sock: {:ssl, ssl_sock}}, status)
    {:error, reason} ->
      disconnect(s, :ssl, "connect", reason)
  end
end
```

Doing some snooping with Wireshark, I was able to see that when connecting successfully with `psql`, I could see packets with `TLSV1.2` as the protocol, but when postgrex was connecting with `ssl: true` I was seeing packets with `SSL` as the protocol before failing to connect.

Looking at the [Ecto.Adapters.Postgres options docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.html#module-options), you'll see there's an `ssl_opts` configuration option which ends up getting passed to `:ssl.connect/3` in which you can set `versions` to override the   TLS version(s) used to connect.

## Solution

I was able to connect to the database by adding the following to my Repo configuration:

```
ssl_opts: [
  versions: [:"tlsv1.2"]
]
```

My full configuration ended up looking like this:

```
config :myapp, Myapp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "myapp@dev-db",
  password: "...",
  database: "myapp_dev",
  port: 5432,
  hostname: "dev-db.postgres.database.azure.com",
  pool_size: 10,
  ssl: true,
  ssl_opts: [
    versions: [:"tlsv1.2"]
  ]
```

I'm not really sure why the TLS version needs to be set explicitly, perhaps someone with more expertise in this area can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to add your ip (or ip range) to the postgres firewall in azure. It's right under the SSL settings.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang is usually built with OpenSSL, and does require it for several libraries. You haven't posted the error you get with `ssl: true`, but if your erlang was built without OpenSSL it might be the cause. From the [build/install guide](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/HOWTO/INSTALL.md):

> OpenSSL -- The opensource toolkit for Secure Socket Layer and
>   Transport Layer Security. Required for building the application
>   crypto. Further, **ssl** and ssh require a working crypto application and
>   will also be skipped if OpenSSL is missing. The public_key application
>   is available without crypto, but the functionality will be very
>   limited.

What output do you get if you run `:ssl.versions()` in an `iex` shell?

Comment: `iex(1)> :ssl.versions()
[ssl_app: '8.1.1', supported: [:"tlsv1.2", :"tlsv1.1", :tlsv1],
 available: [:"tlsv1.2", :"tlsv1.1", :tlsv1, :sslv3]]`

Comment: @nelsonic Based on that output, your erlang is built with openssl, so the issue is not with that. Would be really helpful if you post the error you get with `ssl: true`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Database init() connection code using ssl and certificates. Check your `ssl_opts` settings, maybe.

```
def init() do 
    case Postgrex.start_link(
        hostname: App.Endpoint.config(:dbhost), 
        username: App.Endpoint.config(:username), 
        database: App.Endpoint.config(:dbname), 
        port: App.Endpoint.config(:dbport),
        ssl: true,
        ssl_opts: [
            keyfile: "priv/cert.key",
            certfile: "priv/cert.crt"
        ]) do 
        {:ok, postgrex} ->
            postgrex 
        _ ->
            :error
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answers, here is my `ssl_opts` block when using self-signed certificates and `auth-options` set to `clientcert=verify_full` in your pg_hba.conf. My connection is using TLSv1.3.

```
  ssl_opts: [
     verify: :verify_peer,
     versions: [:"tlsv1.3"],
     ciphers: :ssl.cipher_suites(:all, {3,4}),
     cacertfile: Path.expand("priv/certs/ca-cert.pem"),
     certfile: Path.expand("priv/certs/client-cert.pem"),
     keyfile: Path.expand("priv/certs/client-key.pem")
    ],
```